# Gradle dependency tree for "test" task different in different projects

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle

I am running "gradlew test" task in my 2 android projects- in one it has a dependecy on mergeDebugAssets task while in other it doesn't have.

Though I want my "gradlew test" task to have dependency on mergeDebugAssets because otherwise I am not able to access assets from folder- build/intermediates/bundles/debug in my test.

I don't think it is appropriate to explicitly modify test task for this.

Also, should it depend on android sdk or buildtools version or gradle version? Though I kept the gradle version of 2 projects same but same is happening. Where am I missing?

Comment: But my confusion is why should I explicitly define this. Shouldn't test task actually have a dependency on mergeDebugAssets?

Comment: You might want to use task-tree plugin to definitely see if there is a dependency, https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.dorongold.task-tree . If there is none, it would be your call to set one up. tasks.test.dependsOn('mergeDebugAssets') should do. If you think this should be some default (or just anticipated) behaviour, file a request to the plugin author.

Comment: I got to know the reason. The project with gradle version- 2.1.3 had mergeDebugAssets as dependency of test task but with gradle version 2.3.3, this has been removed. But the problem is how to build the assets for unit test in the latest version? Why should we explicitly add a task to do so?